# Changing color tone on a skin texture

Tags: shaders

Trying to change skin color from white to black and vice versa on a skin texture. Have tried hue/saturation, color ramp, but doesn't come out right. Reading and watching about this it seems you need to do something with subsurface but I can't find a node setup about this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). Please share your material setup and the textures you're using. Blender can do a lot with nodes.

Comment: maybe try to plug your Image Texture into a MixRGB, choose a color and choose the Multiply mode for example, in order to give a slight tint to your image, then plug into the Hue/Saturation

Comment: i added mixrgb and hue/saturation to my node setup and now can control the tone. thank you both for replying and helping.

Answer (score 1):

Plug your *Image Texture* into a *Color > MixRGB* node, in this node choose a color, and choose the *Multiply* mode for example in order to give a slight tint to your image, then plug into the *Hue/Saturation* node and tweak the values to get the color you want.